# thymeleaf: handle "é è à" characters

Tags: thymeleaf

How can I handled strings with accent characters like é, è, à ?
I am getting \u00E9 \u00E0 \u00EE \u00FB \u00FC instead.
Is there an special encoding to apply?

[UPDATE]
Find below the HTML code and java code associated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title ></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
<span th:text="|${proposition.commentaireProposition}|"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Java code that calls the html above :

```
Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag("FR");
Context context = new Context(locale);
context.setVariable("proposition", proposition);
String content = templateEngine.process("propositionPresentationConsultant", context);
```

proposition.commentaireProposition contains é,è,à characters that are not well displayed in the html

Thank you.

Comment: Not enough information given to understand your question.

Comment: I have updated my  post with some code. hope it helps